# How I Inject Repository In Service to avoid Error Some services are not able to be constructed or inject service into injected service asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

When I Inject Repository In Service Constructor (This Error Comes ) Some services are not able to be constructed
[image: my solution]

> Program.Cs

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenreService, GenreService>();

> GenreService

```
  public class GenreService : IGenreService 
    {
        private readonly IRepository<GenresDto> _repositoryGenre;
        public GenreService( IRepository<GenresDto> repositoryGenre)
        {
            _repositoryGenre = repositoryGenre;
        }
```

Comment: Try cleaning up your post a little bit more. I don't think the image of your API is helping, and some of your code is not formatted well.  Also include any error messages.  Lastly, it looks like you may need to specify the type of repository like builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<MyRepository>)... but I could be wrong about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should register the `DbContext` in `program.cs`. So the answer is:

services.AddDbContext(
options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));